# Having issue with extracing date from CLOB data

Tags: oracle, clob

Hi I am having issue when extracting fields from CLOB data. For one record I am not getting desired output.

The record is as below:

```
{1:F014243107336}{2:O2021216200422XXX24563}{3:{108:O2020}{121:2c02a452-5}{433:HIT}}{4:
:4A:SEC:20200901
:4B:FC5253
:4C:20042000,
:4D:XXXXXXX
:4E:RXX
:4F:RXXXX
-}{5:{CHK:87D1003B01F7}{TNG:}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}}<APSECSIGN>FS3sfasdfg!==</APSECSIGN>?
```

I want to extract data from tag :4A: into REF_NUMBER.

I am using below SQL to get the data.

```
NVL(TRIM(TRANSLATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(dbms_lob.substr(CLOB, 4000, 1 ), ':4A.?:[^:]+(:|-\})'), ':20.?:([^:]+)(:|-\})', '\1'),CHR(10)||CHR(13), ' ')),' ') AS REF_NUMBER
```

the output I am getting is "SEC". However I want to see output as SEC:20200901.

Can any one suggest what I am missing in my query or provide me correct query.

Comment: What version of Oracle is your database?

Comment: There are at least three industry standard approaches to storing "structured" data as text, not to mention actually using relational database tables and columns properly. All of them have tool support for extracting values from strings. So why people feel the need to devise their own notation is beyond me. The one thing worse than re-inventing the wheel is re-inventing it square-shaped.

Answer (score 0):

A general suggestion. Why don't you have your data stored as JSON ? Because, JSON related functions are very fast when compared to others. And then your problem becomes quite easy.

However to answer your question:

```
with inputs (str) as
(
    select to_clob(q'<
{1:F014243107336}{2:O2021216200422XXX24563}{3:{108:O2020}{121:2c02a452-5}{433:HIT}}{4:
:4A:SEC:20200901
:4B:FC5253
:4C:20042000,
:4D:XXXXXXX
:4E:RXX
:4F:RXXXX
-}{5:{CHK:87D1003B01F7}{TNG:}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}}<APSECSIGN>FS3sfasdfg!==</APSECSIGN>?
    >') from dual
)
select  str, regexp_substr(str,'SEC:\d+',1,1,'n') as val  
from    inputs;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention it clearly. The value is not always SEC:. Its one of the record I am not able to extract the desired output. my query works fine for all other records except this record, as this record is having one additional ':'

Comment: So, is it after 4A that you always want to extract ?  Eg: :4A:XYZ:20200902 or 4A:RANDOM:20200903 in which case you want XYZ:20200902 and RANDOM:20200903 respectively. Am I understanding it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

If you know the date is always going to be 8 digits after the **:4A:** tag, you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the value you need.  Combining it with `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` removes the tag and converts it to a string.

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR ((REGEXP_SUBSTR (clob_val, ':4A:.*\d{8}')), 4000, 5)
  FROM (SELECT    EMPTY_CLOB ()
               || '{1:F014243107336}{2:O2021216200422XXX24563}{3:{108:O2020}{121:2c02a452-5}{433:HIT}}{4:
:4A:SEC:20200901
:4B:FC5253
:4C:20042000,
:4D:XXXXXXX
:4E:RXX
:4F:RXXXX
-}{5:{CHK:87D1003B01F7}{TNG:}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}}<APSECSIGN>FS3sfasdfg!==</APSECSIGN>?'    AS clob_val
          FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: I tried the above. Seems the tags :4A: and :4B: not always standard in the sequence. I am seeing :4B: is missing for some of the records.  I need to extract the additional : in the data value in the tag :4A:

Comment: Just updated the answer to better handle the missing :4B: tag